# password using Keyvault in ARM template Azure

Tags: azure, password

i want to assign password for a node using keyvault. i want to use a single arm template to get password from keyvault. here i have examples which use template file and a seperate parameter to get the password from keyvault.

Need help on using single ARM template to get password from keyvault and assign it.

Comment: this is crazy, but someone at Microsoft wrote a document about that!  https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2015/11/30/no-more-plaintext-passwords-using-azure-key-vault-with-azure-resource-manager/

Comment: @rob : thanks for the update. here i need to deploy ARM in azure using a tool which will allow to use only one file. so i need to find a way to merge both files and make template to call keyvault value and assign it.

Comment: @BoobalanA whats the tool?

Comment: @Sam:  orbitera is one such but we use our own.

Comment: Your going to struggle to do this without using a parameter file as there is no way to undertake the logic to fetch the value in the ARM script. How are you feeding parameters in now? Or are you just hard coding the default values?

Comment: @Sam as of now i am hardcoding the password to make it work but still looking on how to make the parameter value passed from keyvault in same template.